# When trying to create a new instance of a class get CS7036 C# There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter of

Tags: c#

When trying to create a new instance of a class  get CS7036 C# There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter of

I'm now trying to get the overriding of operators but i'm a beginner and seems that this mistake is kinda funamential, basics. So the functionality I want is that after I press "+" there should be new instance of Employee calss created(c3). I know that is way to simple but I need to undestand how it works before implement more logic. Please help me to fix this and explain why I got this error.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Program
    {
        class Employee
        {
            public string name;
            public int age;
            public Employee(string n, int a) { name = n; age = a; }
            public static Employee operator +(Employee c3)
            {
                return new Employee//here is an Error { name = "Serg", age = 33 };

            }
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Employee c1 = new Employee("Jack", 23);
                Employee c2 = new Employee("John", 45);
                
                Console.WriteLine("To add an employee, press +");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Operator overloading does not react to key presses and is the wrong tool for this. It is for `var c3 = c1 + c2`, which is strange and would give an unrelated Employee

Comment: Use `( )` instead of `{ }`

Comment: Suggestion: do you know about "complex numbers"? There operator overloading makes sense

Comment: Hans Keﬆing I see. Ok but is there  a way to make this functionality so that is could be possible to add new instance of a class simply by keyboard input of "+" ?

Comment: You would have to read the keyboard yourself (possibly [Console.ReadKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readkey) and react (in code) by creating a new instance

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things that need clarification.

You are expecting that operator + will be somehow mapped into the key binding. It's not the case, overriding operators allows you to define for your class operations such as addition or subtraction. For example, you could override operator + for your class `Employee` to return the sum of salaries for two Employees in the type of int, so the addition of two employees would return int like this:

```
var firstEmplyoee = new Employee { Salary = 5000 };
var secondEmplyoee = new Employee { Salary = 2500 };
int sumOfSalaries = firstEmplyoee + secondEmplyoee;
```

I don't see any particular sense for overriding the + operator for `Employee` which results in the creation of yet another `Employee`, so this is why I made up the one with salaries.

I prepared for you a little demo that actually uses input from the keyboard to control the flow of the program, to make the operation on the `Employees` either addition or subtraction. Please note that overridden operators and taking input from the keyboard are two totally different things.

```
class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
    
    public static int operator +(Employee employeeA, Employee employeeB)
    {
        return employeeA.Salary + employeeB.Salary;
    }
    public static int operator -(Employee employeeA, Employee employeeB)
    {
        return employeeA.Salary - employeeB.Salary;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var firstEmplyoee = new Employee { Salary = 5000 };
        var secondEmplyoee = new Employee { Salary = 2500 };

        Console.WriteLine("To add salaries press +, to subtract them press -");
        var key = Console.ReadKey();
        Console.WriteLine();
        if(key.Key == ConsoleKey.Add) // Plus buttton on numeric part of the keyboard.
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Sum of salaries of the employees: {firstEmplyoee + secondEmplyoee}.");
        }
        else if(key.Key == ConsoleKey.Subtract) // Minus buttton on the numeric part keyboard.
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Subtruction of salaries the employees: {firstEmplyoee - secondEmplyoee}.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid key.");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output of the console when I press +:

```
To add salaries press +, to subtract of them press -
+
Sum of salaries of the employees: 7500.
```

Lastly, the chunk of the code that you pointed out as not compiling lacks parenthesis. You can either add there

```
return new Employee { };
```

or

```
return new Employee();
```